Infinite loop problem while applying dynamic routing in next js
My project is in next 13 all things was going good until i used dynamic routing(slug) concept for slowing blog section when i am going to any route like localhost:3000/blogs/3
it is showing infinite loop problem(508 error) i have checked all files but didn't get any clue related to it why it is showing while implementing dynamic routing.
i have gone through all files of code to see that is there not any api calling infinite time but didn't find any api calling infinite

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly recommend checking out the How to Ask documentation, especially the part about including a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Because with the current state of the question, no one will be able to help you.

Thanks Fabio Nettis  ,I am new Developer Thanks for your feedback so that i can improve myself
